# save images and text from a PDF in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to save image PDF and its text in database in asp.net?(as binary)
In my application users need to upload a PDF file that contains several question and Application must extract questions within there images in data base.(of course the questions have a special signed for separating from each other) Is it possible or not?
If yes please guide me?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to do what you looking for :
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129